# External screen random flashing

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, external-monitor

I'm a user of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460s and I've recently started to use an external monitor. Apparently radomly the external screen flash becoming black. It could not happen in an entire day or sometimes really often.

```
sudo lshw -c video
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64)

uname -a
Linux ****** 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with an external SyncMaster P2370HD monitor-HDTV as second display. I upgraded the Ubuntu Desktop to 16.04 LTS and 
then the kernel to 4.9 and this fixed the problem.

```
cat /etc/lsb-*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"

uname -r
4.9.0-040900-generic
```

See kernel [4.9 description](https://www.linux.com/news/linux-kernel-49-here-and-its-largest-release-ever) for further info. 
[This](http://www.askmetutorials.com/2016/12/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-49-on.html) may be will help you to perform the upgrade.